# pug is not responsive

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm using Bootstrap in a pug template, but the layout is not responsive

```
// layout.pug
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l' crossorigin='anonymous')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/register.css')
  body
    block content
```

index

```
extends layout

block content
  .d-flex.flex-column.bd-highlight
    .p-2.bd-highlight.px-0.py-0
      nav.navbar.navbar-light.bg-red.by-5
        .container-fluid
          img(src='../images/iconWhite.png' alt='logo' width='35' height='35')
  script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js' integrity='sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj' crossorigin='anonymous')
  script(src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' integrity='sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns' crossorigin='anonymous')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the layout is not responsive"? What are you expecting? It's just a single nav bar with an image.

Comment: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design)

Answer (score 1):

I only needed this in head

```
meta(charset='utf-8')
meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
```